# Add a property to last item in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    dStep = links[i].getAttribute("data-step"),
    dIntro = links[i].getAttribute("data-intro"),
    linkObj = {
        element: "#step" + dStep,
        intro: dIntro,
        position: "right"
    };
    obj.steps.push(linkObj);
```

How would one add position: "left" to the last item in the loop only?

Comment: Why aren't you declaring any variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// You should almost certainly be using the var keyword
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var dStep = links[i].getAttribute("data-step"),
        dIntro = links[i].getAttribute("data-intro"),
        linkObj = {
            element: "#step" + dStep,
            intro: dIntro,
            position: "right"
        };
    obj.steps.push(linkObj);
}
// Take advantage of the fact that JavaScript doesn't have block scoping
linkObj.position = "left";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (i == len-1) {
   linkObj.position = "left";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    dStep = links[i].getAttribute("data-step"),
    dIntro = links[i].getAttribute("data-intro"),
    linkObj = {
        element: "#step" + dStep,
        intro: dIntro,
        position: "right"
    };

    // try this
    if (i === len - 1) {
        linkObj.position = 'left';
    }

    obj.steps.push(linkObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's the last item you pushed into the array, you could also just add/change the property for the last item in the array after the `for` loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    dStep = links[i].getAttribute("data-step"),
    dIntro = links[i].getAttribute("data-intro"),
    linkObj = {
        element: "#step" + dStep,
        intro: dIntro,
        position: "right"
    };
    obj.steps.push(linkObj);
}

// add this line of code after the for loop
obj.steps[obj.steps.length - 1].position = "left";
```